# Extracting and tokenizing words using nltk - wrong output

Tags: pdf, web-scraping, nltk

I have a text file(converted from pdf) that I want to extract the names from - first of all though I want to tokenize all the words and get nltk to tag them (i.e. PPN for proper noun). 
My code works on one text file but not on another.

The file that works looks like this:

```
1
2
GM HEALTH AND SOCIAL CARE STRATEGIC PARTNERSHIP BOARD
MINUTES OF THE MEETING HELD ON 28 APRIL 2017
Bridgewater Community Healthcare NHS
Dorothy Whitaker
Trust
Bolton Council
Councillor Cliff Morris
Margaret Asquith
```

The file that doesn't work is like this (this one is formatted better to how the actual pdf looked):

```
GREATER MANCHESTER COMBINED AUTHORITY (GMCA) 
ECONOMY, BUSINESS GROWTH AND SKILLS SCRUTINY COMMITTEE 
FRIDAY  13  APRIL  2018  AT  2.00PM,  BOARDROOM,  GMCA, 
CHURCHGATE HOUSE  

Present:  Councillor:  Michael Holly (in the Chair) 

   Councillors:  Susan Haworth (Bolton) 
Roy Walker (Bury) 
Ahmed Ali (Manchester) 
Grace Fletcher-Hackwood (Manchester) 
Kate Lewis (Salford) 
Mark Hunter (Stockport) 
Elise Wilson (Stockport)
```

Here is my code:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('words')
nltk.download('words')

with open('mergedminutes.txt', 'r') as file: 
    data = file.read()
    data2 = data.split()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)

def categorize_words():
    print(pos_tag((tokens)))
output = categorize_words()
file = open("wordsfromminutes.txt", "w")
file.write(str(output))
file.close()
```

I assume it must be something to do with the file. This is the output I get with the second file:

('ÿþI\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00', 'JJ'), ('\x009\x00', 'NNP'), ('\x00', 'NNP'), ('\x00', 'NNP'), ('\x00', 'NNP'), ('\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00_\x00', 'NNP'), ('\x00', 'NNP'), ('\x00', 'NNP'), ('\x00', 'NN

Does anyone have any ideas what could be going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your output of the second file is probably due to an encoding error in the second file. The conversion from pdf to txt may be the cause of the problem.

Try to copy and paste the content of the second file in a new file and save it with a .txt extension. You can use an editor like notepad++, gedit, atom or vim to do that. Then use that file as an input to your program. I was able to get the following output from your program by copying the sample you provided to a .txt file.

[('GREATER', 'NNP'), ('MANCHESTER', 'NNP'), ('COMBINED', 'NNP'), ('AUTHORITY', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('GMCA', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('ECONOMY', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('BUSINESS', 'NNP'), ('GROWTH', 'NNP'), ('AND', 'NNP'), ('SKILLS', 'NNP'), ('SCRUTINY', 'NNP'), ('COMMITTEE', 'NNP'), ('FRIDAY', 'NNP'), ('13', 'CD'), ('APRIL', 'NNP'), ('2018', 'CD'), ('AT', 'NNP'), ('2.00PM', 'CD'), (',', ','), ('BOARDROOM', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('GMCA', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('CHURCHGATE', 'NNP'), ('HOUSE', 'NNP'), ('Present', 'NNP'), (':', ':'), ('Councillor', 'NN'), (':', ':'), ('Michael', 'NNP'), ('Holly', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('Chair', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('Councillors', 'NNS'), (':', ':'), ('Susan', 'NNP'), ('Haworth', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('Bolton', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('Roy', 'NNP'), ('Walker', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('Bury', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('Ahmed', 'NNP'), ('Ali', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('Manchester', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('Grace', 'NNP'), ('Fletcher-Hackwood', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('Manchester', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('Kate', 'NNP'), ('Lewis', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('Salford', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('Mark', 'NNP'), ('Hunter', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('Stockport', 'NNP'), (')', ')'), ('Elise', 'NNP'), ('Wilson', 'NNP'), ('(', '('), ('Stockport', 'NNP'), (')', ')')]

The files and the program I used are available at https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/stackoverflow.com-questions-57148173 .

Writing the output to a file in your version of the program did not work for me. I used the following command to redirect the print output of the program to a file.

```
python extract_names.py > wordsfromdoesntwork.txt
```

I'm using Python 2.7.15+ and nltk 3.4.4.